# copy all text from a browser window with foxpro

Tags: text, browser, foxpro

Years ago, With FoxPro on IE, I was able to to search all browser windows and find the text I wanted. I now need to do that with FoxPro 9 and modern browsers. Just on the active window is fine. If I can download or read the full window I can extract the text I need. Since most popular browsers are based on the same code I assume this would work on any browser but I can tell the users they have to use Chrome if needed.  I'm looking for a string next to a known string on the screen.

Comment: You can use IE and Edge. Where is your code?

Comment: I guess I really need to read the HTML code in the browser.  This is on client PCs running my app in a browser window.  The app is hosted on an AWS server running Thinfinity.  I want to put a code on the server app window that the PC can read to match the two for data exchange.  The customers use a mix of Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Reading HTML code is a different thing and doesn't need a browser. You can read it with DOMDocument. Sorry I don't have an idea about what thinfinity is.